# graph of linked tags

Tags: python, graph

Hi I have a list of lists of linked tag, like this:

```
some_tags = [[u'art', u'interactive', u'media', u'berlin', u'gallery'], [u'event', u'art', u'Istanbul', u'experimental', u'newmedia', u'bioart'], [u'seriousgames', u'installation', u'interaction', u'design', u'art', u'london', u'people'], [u'event', u'art', u'newmedia', u'Istanbul'], [u'art', u'artist', u'interactive', u'installation', u'berlin', u'german', u'people', u'video']]
```

In each sub list there are linked tags. I want to have a dictionary of occurences of links so I can draw the graph. Now I have this code:

```
def remove_all_occurences(l, item):
    return filter(lambda x: x != item, l)

_d = dict()

# occurences dictionary of tags
for taglist in some_tags:
    for tag in taglist:
            if _d.get(tag):
                    _d[tag].extend(taglist)
            else:
                    _d[tag] = taglist
            _d[tag] = remove_all_occurences(_d[tag], tag)

# add counts
for k, taglist in _d.items():
    l = set(taglist)
    _d[k] = [(e,taglist.count(e)) for e in taglist]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(_d)
```

This code works but there are repetitions: 
For example, the link art-video is present two times, first in _d[u'art'] and second in _d[u'video'].
Is there a smart way to make sure there are no repetitions?

Comment: All of them are doubles. How would you want to resolve these links? Or is it not important to you which one you keep?

Comment: In case it is irrelevant you can just change your filter-criterion from `filter(lambda x: x != item, l)` to `filter(lambda x: x > item, l)`.

Comment: the new filter seems to resolve the problem!!! but i don't understand why..

Comment: Because it forces that all items in `d[tag]` are lexicographically after `tag` and thus only one combination is allowed (i.e. a->v but not v->a).

Answer (score 0):

Take a "Map Reduce" approach:

```
from itertools import product, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def generate_pairs(some_tags):
    for linked_tags in some_tags:
        for left,right in product(linked_tags, linked_tags):
            if left != right:
                yield (left, right)

_d=dict()
for key,g in groupby(sorted(generate_pairs(some_tags)), key=itemgetter(0,1)):
    if key[1] in _d and key[0] in [tag for tag, count in _d[key[1]]]:
        continue

    if key[0] not in _d:
        _d[key[0]]=[]

    _d[key[0]] += [(key[1], len([j for j in g]))]
```

Comment: thanks very much this approach is interesting but this does not resolve the problem.. with your code _d['art'] contains video,1 and _d['video'] contains art,1.. the duplication is not resolved..

Comment: I guess I don't completely understand the end-goal.  However, that's just a matter of checking to see if the pair already exists in _d (see updated response).